# Fastest way to get rolling averages in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a list of nodes (about 2300 of them) that have hourly price data for about a year. I have a script that, for each node, loops through the times of the day to create a 4-hour trailing average, then groups the averages by month and hour. Finally, these hours in a month are averaged to give, for each month, a typical day of prices. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this because what I have seems to take a significant amount of time (about an hour). I also save the dataframes as csv files for later visualization (that's not the slow part).

```
df (before anything is done to it)
        Price_Node_Name      Local_Datetime_HourEnding   Price      Irrelevant_column

0       My-node                 2016-08-17 01:00:00        20.95          EST
1       My-node                 2016-08-17 02:00:00        21.45          EST
2       My-node                 2016-08-17 03:00:00        25.60          EST

df_node (after the groupby as it looks going to csv)
Month        Hour             MA
1            0                23.55
1            1                23.45
1            2                21.63


 for node in node_names:
     df_node = df[df['Price_Node_Name'] == node]
     df_node['MA'] = df_node['Price'].rolling(4).mean()
     df_node = df_node.groupby([df_node['Local_Datetime_HourEnding'].dt.month, 
                      df_node['Local_Datetime_HourEnding'].dt.hour]).mean()
     df_node.to_csv('%s_rollingavg.csv' % node)
```

I get an weak error warning me about SetWithCopy, but I haven't quite figured out how to use .loc here since the column ['MA'] doesn't exist until I create it in this snippet and any way I can think of to create it before hand and fill it seems slower than what I have. Could be totally wrong though. Any help would be great.

python 3.6

Comment: How about showing a cut and paste of some of your data?

Comment: I added a few example rows of data before and after the rolling average and hourly averaging.

Comment: Have you tried [`rolling_mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) or [`Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html)?

Comment: I think that most people who use `Pandas` a lot would agree with the statement "if you are using a loop, you're doing it wrong." At the very least, that sentiment has been really helpful to me in learning to find more efficient solutions in `Pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

edit: I might have misread the question here, hopefully this at least sparks some ideas for the solution.

I think it is useful to have the index as the datetime column when working with time series data in Pandas.

Here is some sample data:

```
Out[3]:
                          price
date
2015-01-14 00:00:00  155.427361
2015-01-14 01:00:00  205.285202
2015-01-14 02:00:00  205.305021
2015-01-14 03:00:00  195.000000
2015-01-14 04:00:00  213.102000
2015-01-14 05:00:00  214.500000
2015-01-14 06:00:00  222.544375
2015-01-14 07:00:00  227.090251
2015-01-14 08:00:00  227.700000
2015-01-14 09:00:00  243.456190
```

We use [`Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) to create an `MA` column, i.e. we apply the method to the `price` column, with a two-period window, and call `mean` on the resulting `rolling` object:

```
In [4]: df['MA'] = df.price.rolling(window=2).mean()

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                          price          MA
date
2015-01-14 00:00:00  155.427361         NaN
2015-01-14 01:00:00  205.285202  180.356281
2015-01-14 02:00:00  205.305021  205.295111
2015-01-14 03:00:00  195.000000  200.152510
2015-01-14 04:00:00  213.102000  204.051000
2015-01-14 05:00:00  214.500000  213.801000
2015-01-14 06:00:00  222.544375  218.522187
2015-01-14 07:00:00  227.090251  224.817313
2015-01-14 08:00:00  227.700000  227.395125
2015-01-14 09:00:00  243.456190  235.578095
```

And if you want `month` and `hour` columns, can extract those from the index:

```
In [7]: df['month'] = df.index.month  

In [8]: df['hour'] = df.index.hour

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
                          price          MA  month  hour
date
2015-01-14 00:00:00  155.427361         NaN      1     0
2015-01-14 01:00:00  205.285202  180.356281      1     1
2015-01-14 02:00:00  205.305021  205.295111      1     2
2015-01-14 03:00:00  195.000000  200.152510      1     3
2015-01-14 04:00:00  213.102000  204.051000      1     4
2015-01-14 05:00:00  214.500000  213.801000      1     5
2015-01-14 06:00:00  222.544375  218.522187      1     6
2015-01-14 07:00:00  227.090251  224.817313      1     7
2015-01-14 08:00:00  227.700000  227.395125      1     8
2015-01-14 09:00:00  243.456190  235.578095      1     9
```

Then we can use `groupby`:

```
In [11]: df.groupby([
    ...:     df['month'],
    ...:     df['hour']
    ...: ]).mean()[['MA']]
Out[11]:
                    MA
month hour
1     0            NaN
      1     180.356281
      2     205.295111
      3     200.152510
      4     204.051000
      5     213.801000
      6     218.522187
      7     224.817313
      8     227.395125
      9     235.578095
```

Comment: He's using `Series.rolling()` here : `df_node['Price'].rolling(4).mean()`

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much what I was doing. Though doing the rolling mean here is technically more accurate as it rolls through midnight whereas what I have, or doing it after the monthly hourly averaging stops at midnight and starts rolling again the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things to try:

set 'Price_Node_name' to the index before the loop

```
df.set_index('Price_Node_name', inplace=True)
for node in node_names:
    df_node = df[node]
```

use `sort=False` as a kwarg in the groupby

```
df_node.groupby(..., sort=False).mean()
```

Perform the rolling average AFTER the groupby, or don't do it at all--I don't think you need it in your case. Averaging the hourly totals for a month will give you the expected values for a typical day, which is what you desire. If you still want the rolling average, perform it on the averaged hourly totals for each month.

Comment: I got so caught up in the code that I didn't think through the statistics! Definitely going to do a rolling average after the monthly hourly averaging if I need to do it at all. Will report back on speed of both the suggestions.